# QGLWidget paintEvent: where to initialize openGL?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, graphics, qglwidget

It seems that the paintEvent method of the QGLWidget is called before initializeGL, so where am I supposed to put my openGL initialization code?

I'm putting it into the paintEvent method like this:

```
void MyGLWidget::paintEvent(...)
{
   makeCurrent();
   ..save modelview and projection matrices..

   // This is initialization code

   GLenum init = glewInit();
    if (GLEW_OK != init)
    {
      /* Problem: glewInit failed, something is seriously wrong. */
      qWarning() << glewGetErrorString(init);
    }

    // Dark blue background
    glClearColor(0.2f, 0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f);
    // Enable depth test
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);


   // End initialization code

   ... drawing code

   QPainter painter(this);
   ...overpainting..

}
```

I really don't like the idea of having my glew library initialization function called every time a paintEvent is raised... although that's working.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to initialize OpenGL in initializeGL(), there is no other option.

But you also have to draw inside [paintGL](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/qglwidget.html#paintGL), not inside paintEvent, so that is where your mistake is.

Comment: If I call "updateGL" from paintEvent, and let initializeGL and paintGL do the work, for some reason the screen is rendered okay but then is immediately swapped entirely white. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

Override initializeGL() function of QGLWidget. It is Created right for the purposes you want

From it's documentation:

> This virtual function is called once before the first call to
>   paintGL() or resizeGL(), and then once whenever the widget has been
>   assigned a new QGLContext. Reimplement it in a subclass.

link to documentation: http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/qglwidget.html#initializeGL

Comment: as I said, it seems initializeGL is called AFTER paintEvent, so I can't draw in paintEvent without glew extensions and shaders set (which should be done, in my humble opinion, into initializeGL)

Comment: @JohnPell: sorry, I did not notice that. Are you sure it's called after paint event? Try to put break points in both functions and check which one is triggered first

Comment: I did that, that's why I wrote that initializeGL is called after paintEvent. It's weird but seems so

Comment: @JohnPell: have you tried putting breakpoints to see if paint is really called before initialize ?

Comment: yes, I tried with breakpoints, and it's not necessary to put breakpoints because if I put the initialization code into initializeGL and the normal drawing code in paintEvent, the scene crashes because initializeGL isn't called before paintEvent